# What controls scrollback in a terminal window?

Tags: ssh, terminal, scrolling

I'm using `gnome-terminal` with unlimited scrollback set

[image]

On my local machine, and certain remote machines which I connect to via ssh, I can scrollback using both the scroll wheel on the mouse, and by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd>.

On other remote machines I am not able to scrollback at all. Using the scroll wheel on the mouse cycles through previous commands (as if by pressing up), and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd> has no effect (other than sounding a beep).

AFAIK I am not using gnu-screen, tmux etc. I am opening a terminal locally and then ssh to the remote machine.

One thing to note is that the remote machine is a Google Compute Engine VM running their stock Ubuntu 18.04 image. Perhaps there is something unusual about the Ubuntu image GCE is running?

Having run htop on the remote server, this is the process hierarchy:

```
/sbin/init
+-- /usr/sbin/sshd -D
    +-- sshd: steve [priv]
        +-- sshd: steve@pts/0
            +-- -bash
                +-- htop
```

So it doesn't seem as if there is another process which is switching to *alternate screen*, as suggested by [@egmont](https://superuser.com/users/278816/egmont)

- What is controlling the ability to scrollback?
- Is there a way to enable it on the remote machines where it doesn't currently work?

Comment: _Shift_ + Page Up you mean?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct - updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Any app running inside the terminal emulator can control the *ability* to scroll back, by switching to the *alternate screen* or back to the *normal screen*.

The normal screen has the scrollback of the configured size. The alternate screen doesn't have a scrollback. Certain terminal emulators might convert mouse scroll events to up/down keypresses while on the alternate screen, perhaps conditionally to the *alternate scroll mode*.

Alternate screen is typically used by fullscreen applications such as ncurses apps, text viewers/editors, screen/tmux/byobu etc. Check which one of these is running on your remote host (or locally before you ssh).

Comment: I updated the question with more details. I am running a stock Ubuntu 18.04 image provided by Google Compute Engine. I am not, myself, running tmux, screen etc, but I guess perhaps GCE is running one. I'll check and report back. Thanks for the answer btw!

Comment: I have updated my question to show I have found nothing which is switching to *alternate screen*

Comment: htop does switch to the alternate screen.

Comment: htop is not running when I attempt to scroll - I only ran htop to view the tree of processes from my shell up to sshd